# How to add a live console session inside an imbeded window to LightTable?

Tags: linux, windows, console, cross-platform, lighttable

It would be nice to have an imbedded console within a sub-window within LightTable to reduce the amount of open windows during development for all programing languages. Preferably this would work for all platforms, but at the least one for Linux would be really nice.