# How to add a live (interactive) console window to Atom?

Tags: console-application, atom-editor

Is it possible to add a live (interactive) console window to Atom?  Note that this is similar to the article on [adding a live console session to LightTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658490/how-to-add-a-live-console-session-inside-an-imbeded-window-to-lighttable), except that it is for Atom.

Essentially, I am interested in the integrated terminal emulation that [Geany](http://www.geany.org) is capable of doing:
[image: Geany - integrated terminal emulation]

Is there any way to do this in the Atom text editor from Github?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You might take a look at [Atom Terminal Panel](https://atom.io/packages/atom-terminal-panel) packages.

Comment: okay thanks! not perfect (it doesn't run vi/vim, for example), but otherwise it works!

Comment: @nathanielng My pleasure! You might create new issue on package repo. Maybe author of the package can help :)

Comment: this doesn't work on ubuntu....ctrl + shift + t does nothing for me. Occassionally it will open a Gnome terminal but is not integrated into the panel. This is just buggy

Comment: @kristen atom-terminal is broken, use platformio-atom-ide-terminal instead.

Comment: Too bad about all these things being "panels". Is it asking so much to have it in a tab?

Comment: @nathanchere sure, with [terminal-tab](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-tab). Also worth to mention the most popular [terminal-plus](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus)

Answer (score 14):

Yes it is possible. Don't know how they did, but there is a package "paltformio-ide". Installing it would add the windows powershell in atom, like this one:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I started using **platformio-ide-terminal**. Project URL: https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal

[image]
[image]

Comment: Works with gitbash `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`

Answer (score 6):

Being used to webstorm live console I like [terminal-plus](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus) a lot
[image]

Comment: I love it, too. terminal-plus is the No.1 downloaded package as of today.

Answer (score 2):

I recomend you use "platformio-ide-terminal"

Comment: it is platformio-ide-terminal

Answer (score 1):

**platformio-ide-terminal** should be better because it was fork of terminal-plus.

and most of the features and usage are same as terminal-plus.

read some docs here and you will love it.
https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal

Comment: I liked the `platformio-ide` and `platformio-ide-terminal`. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Boy, do things change.  As of May 2018, terminal-panel, atom-terminal-panel and terminal-plus haven't been updated in years and aren't compatible with the new versions of Atom.

At the moment, platformio-ide-terminal also doesn't support the latest stable version of Atom (1.26) - it's only been maintained up to Atom 1.25.  platformio-ide-terminal is also the terminal for platformio-ide, an IoT IDE.  I don't recommend it for non-IoT applications.

So there doesn't seem to be a good terminal application for Atom's non-IoT use cases right now, unless you want to use an old version of Atom.

Comment: `platformio-ide-terminal` working ok with latest `atom 1.41` in Arch Linux

Answer (score 1):

The most recent versions of atom-ide-ui now provide an integrated terminal that you can open (default keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shft</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> on MacOS).

It seems to be pretty smoothly integrated, even properly using all your normal environment options.