# How to open command prompt in Atom editor?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, atom-editor

How can I run command prompt in Atom Editor? Do I need to install any package for the same? I could not find any videos or links regarding this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787116/how-to-add-a-live-See: interactive-console-window-to-atom

Answer (score 11):

Go to `File -> Settings -> Install`

Search for package -> `platformio-ide-terminal`

After installation of this package

Go to `Packages tab in a menu bar` where you can see all the packages installed

click on `platformio-ide-terminal -> New Terminal` [Now you will get the terminal window]

Comment: `platformio-ide-terminal` opens powershell by default. To change to command prompt see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277302/change-terminal-in-atom-editors-platformio-ide-terminal-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 packages that I use to open a terminal window in Atom. They are 'platformio-ide-terminal' and Termination. Load either one of these and the name will appear under the package menu. Selecting either one will allow you to open a terminal window in bottom third of Atom window.